# Can't find an appropriate xpath directory. Need some advice

Tags: xpath

```
<div> 
<div class="dates">
```

So, to find the dates class above, I'm using `$x("//div[@class= 'dates']//")` but console says that this expression is illegal expression.

```
<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 870px; margin: 0px auto;">
<div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 0px;">
<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 870px; margin: 0px auto;">
<div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 91px;">
<ul id="DateList" class="bxslider clearfix" data-bx-slider="mode: 'horizontal', pager: false, controls: false, minSlides: 1, maxSlides:4, slideWidth: 290, slideMargin:0, hideControlOnEnd:true, infiniteLoop: false, moveSlides: 1" style="width: 515%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
```

To find the correct xpath to the above node, I'm using $x("//ul[@id= 'DateList']//") and still got a message that expression is illegal.

```
<li class="date-block slide ng-scope" data-notify-when-repeat-finished="" ng-repeat="dates in cruiseFinder.filters.sailDates" style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 290px;">
<h5 class="ng-binding">2015</h5>
<ul id="months" class="months">
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases the last double slash is too many: The right xpaths would be:

- `//div[@class= 'dates']`
- `//ul[@id= 'DateList']`

Double slash into a xpath expression means "in any place of the document".

Comment: May I use double slashes if I want to continue building my xpath deeper?

Comment: Of corse, but the double slash, as the simple slash, must be _prior_ to any other xpath selector: a node selector, an attribute selector... Therefore, it must not be at the end of the xpath.